# Why Galaxy SII reports on not enough memory for new apps when I have several GBs available on flash storage?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 4.1-jelly-bean, insufficient-memory

I have 5GB free out of total 11.5GB internal flash storage on my SGS2.

However, it doesn't allow to install new apps saying there's not enough memory. Also `Settings > Applications Manager > All` reports 1.7GB used, 281MB free (even immediately after reboot).

Why I can't use all 11.5GB of internal storage for my apps, but only 2GB? How can I make more storage available for applications?

Samsung Galaxy SII, stock firmware auto-updated to 4.1.2 I9100 XWLSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s-ii/272384-galaxy-s2-cannot-download-updates-new-apps.html) helped me:

- since firmware version 4.1 (Jelly Bean), the memory became partitioned: roughly 2GB for apps, the rest became mass storage. The problem didn't exist in ICS or earlier.
- to free up *some* space, dial *#9900# *in standard dialer (called Phone)* and select option 2 "Delete dumpstate/logcat" in the prompted menu

As for making more than 2GBs available for applications, [here's an instruction](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2538947) on re-flashing firmware which re-partitions internal storage, allowing up to 12GBs of internal storage for applications.

Answer (score 2):

The Samsung Galaxy SII is an older device which doesn't use the MTP protocol and so, applications' storage and internal storage is separated. Newer devices share the full internal storage seemingly.

If you in need of storage space for apps, you may look at some root options such as:

- app2sd applications that enable you to transfer your applications to the internal storage
- app2ext that enable you to extend your applications' partition
- a ROM for your phone that change the partitions' size

Answer (score 1):

What my friend is implying is that the applications you have on your Samsung, are eating up your Internal memory. What you need is to get the applications running from your external SD card.

In all android devices there's an amount of the memory assigned to run your android system just like in a computer there's a storage for your OS.This storage should be about 2GB, or less....now, your Samsung's memory is divided into three main parts,that is system storage , USB storage and SD card(external SD card)Try going to your task manager and checking the available memory.

also, Try moving the apps to run on SD card(external) using [AppsMgrIII](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en), hope it works.Otherwise if the memory continues to be as little as you imply, your S2 will start getting slower.Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to free up some space is SD Maid. It's a free software and is available on the Android Market. Sometimes log files take a lot of this internal space. But I believe even ~200MB should be more than enough to get new apps. Have you tried writing to the internal storage yourself or check if apps can write to it? This is easy to do if you have a rooted phone and you can use any file manager to create a file on it. I suspect that your phone is accidentally detecting your internal storage as read only and this is what is causing the issue. I have seen the same happen for external SD cards before but not for internal storage.